# Remove timestamp appended to Puma process name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, server, process, puma

I'm trying to remove a timestamp that's appended to the end of the Puma process name. Application is a rails app using Puma and Nginx hosted on a Ubuntu server.

puma 3.11.2 (unix:///home/ubuntu/apps/my-application/shared/tmp/sockets/level-puma.sock) [20181011151522]

I have checked the Puma configuration as well as the Nginx configuration files and don't see a way to remove the timestamp.

Out of a handful of servers there's only one that's got the timestamp at the end. The others don't have it and there's nothing different about the config.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using Capistrano for deploy, thus this timestamp is the running release version. But you can add the 'tag' option in your puma´s config to be set in your process´s name. Check out the documentation in the link below:

https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/master/examples/config.rb#L174-L179